# DECODE_RAW the TensorSliceDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.0

I am replicating TTS model, Deep Voice 3. 
Dataset is LJSpeech-1.1. I found a github repo (https://github.com/Kyubyong/deepvoice3) but it was written in earlier tensorflow version where I am using TF 2.0. 
In data processing, I need to apply decode_raw function to the output of TensorSliceDataset. 
But, I can't apply decode_raw function to the output. 
**So, my question is how can I apply decode_raw to the output of TensorSliceDataset?**

I have converted to the text into tensor with dimension (13066,). 
In the original repo, he used tf.train.slice_input_producer. 
For TF 2.0, I am using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices to convert that tensor into TensorSliceDataset. 
After that, I can't apply decode_raw to TensorSliceDataset. Below is the code

```py
# old TF code
texts, mels, dones, mags = tf.train.slice_input_producer([texts, mels, dones, mags], shuffle = True)
# TF 2.0 code
texts = tf.convert_to_tensor(texts)
texts = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(texts)
texts = tf.io.decode_raw(texts, tf.int32) # (None,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply parse function to a dataset object. 
Instead of this line

```
texts = tf.io.decode_raw(texts, tf.int32) # (None,)`
```

use

```
texts = texts.map(lambda x: tf.io.decode_raw(x, tf.int32))
```